# Windows Hardware Lab Kit (HLK) hangs on WFP Validation when trying to WFPLogo

Tags: wfp

Why is WFPLogo.exe hanging for the Validate WFP test?

I setup HLK 10 on Windows Server 2016 for controller and test server.  I scheduled tasks for my WFP driver and the first two suites completed successfully.  However, the WindowsFilteringPlatform_tests hands on Validated WFPUsage and it seems to be running:

```
WFPLogo.Exe -t "\ArchitecturalDesign\Validate.WFPUsage" -l
Filter.Driver.WindowsFilteringPlatform.ArchitecturalDesign.Validate.WFPUsage.NTLog
-r
```

When I run this locally, the tool opens a file with a series of questions for me to fill out and save.   I don't quite know how to configure my HLK studio project so it already has the information so they system doesn't halt.

I hope that if I save once then it updates config across the entire machine so I can then rerun the suite and get past this hangup.  If that fails, I guess, I can try to login as the test user and run the test.  Since the test must run as elevated admin and I performed the config as that user, I might be ok?

This still seems wrong, I'd expect to configure this in the project.

Am I missing a step on the HLK setup and project configuration?

Thanks

Eva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have a partial answer.  On HLK controller the default WFPLogo.info files in

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Hardware Lab Kit\Tests

amd64\nttest\NetTest\SecureNet\WFPTest

and

x86\nttest\NetTest\SecureNet\WFPTest

need to be replace with your customized version.  At least this seems to have worked in my case.

also be sure:

- "UseAnswerFile = 1" in WFPLogo.info
- provider.displayData.* match values in WFPLogo.info (see [msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bcad7de2-6d39-4f4c-94d4-54bddd7e760a/hck-wfplogo-test-fwpmprovidersmaintainidentifying-fails-frequently-but-not-always?forum=wfp))

The provider.displayData.name must equal the string value of the WFPLogo.Info's CompanyName.

The provider.displayData.description must contain the string value of the WFPLogo.Info's ProductName.